combine several rows into one using Pandas
I have a dataset of lab results from patients on different dates. I want to combine each patient's results into a single row. The types and number of lab results are unlimited.
I tried to simplify my goal in the following picture:


Can you please share example data as dataframes not as pictures? Also, please share your attempt to solve the problem.

Check the #10 in the duplicate
